composition of representations
Let $\rho:G \to {\rm{Aut}}(V)$ be a linear representation of a finite group. Now consider the map ${\rm{Aut}}(V) \to {\rm{Aut}}({\rm{End}}(V))$ obtained by letting act linear automorphisms on ${\rm{End}}(V)$ on the left. The composition of these two maps yields a representation $G \to {\rm{Aut}}({\rm{End}}(V))$. What is the character of this representation ? After some computation, I found that it is $n \cdot \chi_\rho$ where $n$ is the dimension of $V$ and $\chi_{\rho}$ is the character of the representation $\rho$. (Hopefully this is correct.) But I would have liked to know if there is a more conceptual way of doing it.
For instance, if $V$ is a representation, then ${\rm{Hom}}(V,V)$ is also a representation by setting $$ (g \cdot f)(v) = g \cdot f(g^{-1} \cdot v), f \in {\rm{Hom}}(V,V) = {\rm{End}}(V), g \in G, v \in V$$
In this case, ${\rm{End}}(V) \simeq V^{*} \otimes V$ and taking the characters on both sides yields $$\chi_{{\rm{End}}(V)} = \chi_{V^{*}}(g) \cdot \chi_{V}(g) = \chi_{V}(g^{-1}) \cdot \chi_{V}(g).$$
However, the action on ${\rm{End}}(V)$ here is different so this line of thought would need to be adapted in order to work.
